# Weird shadow effect

Tags: lighting

There are weird shadows on my model and I have no idea why. [image]

I thought it was because there was no lighting inside the model, but when I added in lights the problem still continued to persist.
[image]

Comment: Could you explicitate which are the weird shadows?

Comment: Those black areas near the bottom of the glass dome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a smoothing artifact, caused by the pronounced angle on the border of the glass. You can check Autosmooth in Mesh/Normals to get rid of it.

[image: Smooth shading with and without Autosmooth]

Note that Autosmmoth is a render trick (as well as Smooth shading), it doesn't actually modify the mesh. So for some cases, it won't work well. As an alternative, you can use a Edgesplit modifier instead : it will physically cut the edges, instead of simply adjusting the normals.

Comment: Thank you! This was bugging me for a few days and I was clueless on how to fix it.